# Why won't my javascript function called after ajax.success?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Why won't my function work after ajax has succeed?

I have a custom function named filter(), defined in the header as javascript file. 
Then i have a series of jquery code to dynamically retrieve data from the server to populate the select box. I would like to call the filter() after the AJAX request has completed since the filter() will manage populated the select box's option.

```
$.ajax({
url: "checkersc2.php", //This is the page where you will handle your SQL insert
type: "GET",
data: values, //The data your sending to some-page.php
success: function (response) {
    $('#loading-image').css('display', 'none');
    $dropdownCondition.html(response);
    filter();
},
error: function () {
    console.log("AJAX request was a failure");
}
});
```

EDIT: my filter() code is a little long, @ http://jsfiddle.net/tongky20/re5unf7p/11/

Comment: And what is the problem? If the `filter()` function isn't working, posting it would probably be a good idea ?

Comment: Could you please post the code of `filter`? Thanks

Comment: @Christos Hi, please check my post :)

Comment: You have not posted the code of your `filter()` function @OASHAHA. Please post it.

Comment: Please explain more clearly what's going wrong. The title says that the function isn't being called. Is that really true? If you put a breakpoint in the function, it doesn't stop there?

Comment: @JayBlanchard It is on the link that i've posted. Pretty complicated stuff i have made.. guess i am still new to this

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have an invalid selector for dropdownCondition. It probably fails on that line and never calls filter. Unless you defined that variable else where try updating it to a valid element selector and see if it calls filter. Something like:

```
$('#dropdownCondition').html(response);
```

Assuming the element id is dropdownCondition.

Full function:

```
$.ajax({
url: "checkersc2.php", //This is the page where you will handle your SQL insert
type: "GET",
data: values, //The data your sending to some-page.php
success: function (response) {
    $('#loading-image').css('display', 'none');
    $('#dropdownCondition').html(response);
    filter();
},
error: function () {
    console.log("AJAX request was a failure");
}
});
```

Comment: It's not about the selector, I have var $dropdownCondition = $('#dropdownCondition'); before that.

Comment: Are you sure it is in scope of that function? Set a breakpoint on that line and see if it is defined. If it is defined the other code will be required. Other than that a fiddle would be best.